# Drools mode stream and containers

Tags: stream, drools, mode

HI this is my code.

```
public static KieContainer createKieContainerForProject() {
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        // Create a module model
        KieModuleModel kieModuleModel = ks.newKieModuleModel();

        // Base Model from the module model
        KieBaseModel kieBaseModel = kieModuleModel.newKieBaseModel( "KBase" )
                .setDefault( true )
                .setEqualsBehavior( EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY)
                .setEventProcessingMode( EventProcessingOption.STREAM );                

        // Create session model for the Base Model
        KieSessionModel ksessionModel = kieBaseModel.newKieSessionModel( "KSession" )
                .setDefault( true )
                .setType( KieSessionModel.KieSessionType.STATEFUL )
                .setClockType( ClockTypeOption.get("realtime") );

        // Create File System services
        KieFileSystem kFileSystem = ks.newKieFileSystem();

        File file = new File("src/main/resources/rules/Sample.drl");
        Resource resource = ks.getResources().newFileSystemResource(file).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
    kFileSystem.write( resource );       

        KieBuilder kbuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kFileSystem );
        // kieModule is automatically deployed to KieRepository if successfully built.
        kbuilder.buildAll();

        if (kbuilder.getResults().hasMessages(org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Build time Errors: " + kbuilder.getResults().toString());
        }    
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
        return kContainer;
    }
```

}

it's dont work when I call the fucntion, and my rules no work too.

my rule is

```
    rule "Sound the alarm in case temperature rises above threshold"
        when
          TemperatureThreshold( $max : max )
          Number( doubleValue > $max ) from accumulate(
              SensorReading( $temp : temperature ) over window:time( 10m ),
              average( $temp ) )
    then
        // sound the alarm
    end
```

when I run the program, He says it has error, mode not stream and the code dont work.

how do I put a program in stream mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REduce your code, and add -KieBase and KieSession creation:

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kFileSystem = ks.newKieFileSystem();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "...drl" );

    kFileSystem.write("src/main/resources/somename.drl",
              ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) ); //XXX

    KieBuilder kbuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kFileSystem );
    kbuilder.buildAll();
    if (kbuilder.getResults().hasMessages(org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Build time Errors: " + kbuilder.getResults().toString());
    }    
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

    KieBaseConfiguration config = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
    config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);

    KieBase kieBase = kContainer.newKieBase( config );
    KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
```

This should give you a session that's capable of running your rule. (

Comment: tks, but my drls don't work now. The code is ok , it compile. I call the fireAllRules, but it does nothing.

Comment: This could have a number of reasons. To check that your session does contain the rules from your DRL file, add one rule: `rule hello when then System.out.println( "hello" ); end` - Running a session in STREAM using a realtime clock can be tricky, but I don't see how you do that and how you insert facts.

Comment: I did one example simple.I did like the hello world along with his example. But i dont know how i can see my rules. But the kContainer has different initiation.
it is my code : [github](https://gist.github.com/eliezerlribeiro/f98de6c31fa8dfec12cd)
and my drls :[github](https://gist.github.com/eliezerlribeiro/1dfa0ac384a658d19d0c)

Comment: Oops. Somehow I lost one line when trying to adapt my code to your variable names etc. Please add the missing line marked "XXX". Sorry.

Comment: I also changed the code, for this:  KieSession kSession = **kieBase**.newKieSession(); and works. tks

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e9988), it's as follows:

```java
KieBaseConfiguration config = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieBaseConfiguration();
config.setOption( EventProcessingOption.STREAM );
```

But it's probably worth taking a look at [this Drools test](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/dd59435b623cc5dfdbb3ba9b0ff18b187fc3bc79/drools-decisiontables/src/test/java/org/drools/decisiontable/CalendarTimerResourcesTest.java) for a working example.